# JBPM retrieve resource XML path or file object

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, business-process-management, drools-flow

Is there a way to retieve `"sample.bpmn"` path or File object from `StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession` object or from `KnowledgeBase kbase` object ?

```
 public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        // start a new process instance
        ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");
        System.out.println("Process started ...");
    }

private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("sample.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2);
    return kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because that's being compiled  by the builder. 
Why do you need to get the file back? if you already have it in your file system/classpath?

Comment: Need to access XML content from other JVM where ProcessInstance object is given .

Comment: Got the solution : ProcessInstance  > Process > ClassPathResource > getUrl()